# svelte reactivity inside the on:pointerup arrow function inside the div

Tags: javascript, css, svelte, svelte-component

```
<div class="menuBar">     
    {#if tickerOpen}
    <div class='tickerMenu' 

    style='background-color: {globalMenuSelection.tickerColor[globalMenuSelection.currentMenuTickerSelection].primaryTf};opacity:1'>
    {#each orderedTickerItems as item, index}
    <span class="tickerMenuItems" 
    style="
    top: {index * 42 + 0.5}px;
    background-color: {tickerHoveredIndex === index ? globalMenuSelection.tickerColor[globalMenuSelection.currentMenuTickerSelection].secondaryTf : globalMenuSelection.tickerColor[globalMenuSelection.currentMenuTickerSelection].primaryTf}"
    on:pointerdown={(event) => {
        tickerMenuScrolling = false;
        initialTickerMenuPointerPos = {
            x: event.clientX || event.touches[0].clientX,
            y: event.clientY || event.touches[0].clientY,
        };
        tickerMenuPointerDownTimestamp = Date.now();            
    }}
    on:pointermove={(event)=>{
        const currentPointerPosition = {
            x: event.clientX || event.touches[0].clientX,
            y: event.clientY || event.touches[0].clientY,
        };
        const distanceX = Math.abs(currentPointerPosition.x - initialTickerMenuPointerPos.x);
        const distanceY = Math.abs(currentPointerPosition.y - initialTickerMenuPointerPos.y);
        if (distanceX > tickerMenuScrollThreshold || distanceY > tickerMenuScrollThreshold) {
            tickerMenuScrolling = true;
        }
    }}
    on:pointerup={(event)=>{
        if(!tickerMenuScrolling){
            const timeElapsed = Date.now() - tickerMenuPointerDownTimestamp
            if(timeElapsed <= tickerMenuTimeThreshold){
                //treat it as a tap/click event
                tickerOpen = false
                currentlyVisibleTickerImageOnMenu = item.var
                globalMenuSelection.currentMenuTickerSelection = item.name

                //ticker change from old -> old initiation is instant. can immediately trigger the animation process for below
                if(globalMenuSelection.isWsAndFetchOngoing === false){
                    //start the animation process immediately
                    rootBody.transition = 'background-color 0.6s, background-image 0.6s'
                    rootBody.backgroundColor = globalMenuSelection.tickerColor[item.name].primaryOrder
                    rootBody.backgroundImage = `radial-gradient(circle, ${globalMenuSelection.tickerColor[item.name].secondaryOrder} 14%, transparent 10%)`
                    rootBody.backgroundSize = "7px 7px";
                }

            }
        }
    }}
    
    </span>
    {/each}
    </div>
    {/if}
```

I have a menu div above
I've implemented a menu selection on pointerdown

take a look at the logic inside the on:pointerup arrow function below. I'm animating the change of background color from the previous state to the current state based on which menu item was selected.

```
on:pointerup={(event)=>{
    if(!tickerMenuScrolling){
        const timeElapsed = Date.now() - tickerMenuPointerDownTimestamp
        if(timeElapsed <= tickerMenuTimeThreshold){
            //treat it as a tap/click event
            tickerOpen = false
            currentlyVisibleTickerImageOnMenu = item.var
            globalMenuSelection.currentMenuTickerSelection = item.name

            //ticker change from old -> old initiation is instant. can immediately trigger the animation process for below
            if(globalMenuSelection.isWsAndFetchOngoing === false){
                //start the animation process immediately
                rootBody.transition = 'background-color 0.6s, background-image 0.6s'
                rootBody.backgroundColor = globalMenuSelection.tickerColor[item.name].primaryOrder
                rootBody.backgroundImage = `radial-gradient(circle, ${globalMenuSelection.tickerColor[item.name].secondaryOrder} 14%, transparent 10%)`
                rootBody.backgroundSize = "7px 7px";
            }

        }
    }
}}
```

i have a condition called `globalMenuSelection.isWsAndFetchOngoing`
this is a boolean that changes from false to true to false dynamically

if it is false, then the animation of the background color change occurs like I would expect.

if it is true, then no color change occurs

and when it dynamically changes from true back to false, because it is not reactive, it doesn't change the background color.

how can i implement reactivity around the `globalMenuSelection.isWsAndFetchOngoing` boolean without changing my existing code too much?

Comment: You should extract the functions to the `<script>`, this is a mess.

Comment: If you want something to happen reactively, use [reactive statements (`$: ...`)](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive), not events. The event should just change state or start timers, etc.

Comment: thanks I will try your suggestions and clean it up